# extjs 4 scroilling WITHOUT a scrollbar

Tags: extjs

I have this narrow panel which is basically a list of thumbnails, and i need to be able to scroll over them using buttons.
We have a panel (anchor layout), with containers in it, and each container contains the image.

there isn't space for a scrollbar, and anyway we don't want one.

I thought it would be as easy as in the listener for my button calling panel.getEL().scroll('b',20)
but this isn't working because the scrollHeight === ClientHeight so scroll does nothing.

Is there a technique I am missing or should this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're using a button to scroll through the images? What about having the button's listener remove/hide the containers/images at the front of the panel to allow the others to use the space?

Comment: Thanks I will start work on this this morning, I was blinkered.